# Django queryset is returning none or empty

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to print/get whatever is in the `Property.applicable_platform.event_group` but when I try to print them out I get a empty queryset:

```
parser.EventGroups.None
or
<QuerySet []>
```

Here is my models currently setup.

```
class Device(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class EventGroups(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class PlatformDevice(models.Model):
    name = 'Property Specifics'
    property_field = models.ForeignKey('Property', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    event_group = models.ManyToManyField('EventGroups', blank=True)
    applicable_devices = models.ManyToManyField('Device', blank=True)


class Platform(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class Property(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    applicable_platform = models.ManyToManyField(Platform, through=PlatformDevice)
```

I can successfully print the device names but I can not print the event_groups names as it returns empty. I have a bunch of test EventGroups added in my admin panel and if I print out the objects then I can see them.

Answer (score 0):

Your *through* table needs to have `ForeignKey` fields referencing both tables in the Many-To-Many relationship:

```
class PlatformDevice(models.Model):
    name = 'Property Specifics'
    event_group = models.ForeignKey('EventGroups', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    applicable_devices = models.ForeignKey('Device', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

Then, to make a query, use the `ManyToMany` field from the corresponding model:

```
properties = Property.objects.all()
event_groups = properties.applicable_platform.all()
```

Comment: I need them to be ManyToMany. applicable_devices works fine. but not event_groups and they are both the same in terms of structure.

Answer (score 0):

1- Apparently you want create many-to-many between Property and Platform, with the through model as PlatformDevice. So the m2m field needs to declare ForeignKey to Platform in PlatformDevice

```
class PlatformDevice(models.Model):
    name = 'Property Specifics'
    property_field = models.ForeignKey('Property', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    event_group = models.ManyToManyField('EventGroups', blank=True)
    applicable_devices = models.ManyToManyField('Device', blank=True)
    platform = models.ForeignKey('Platform', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Furthermore you don't have any ForeignKey between Platform and EventGroups.

so Platform query (applicable_platform) has no attribute 'event_group'

you can create m2m between Property and , with the through model as PlatformDevice

Or 
2- you can change applicable_devices and event_group m2m relation to ForeignKey and create m2m relation between Property and Platform with the through model as PlatformDevice and add through_fields=('event_group', 'applicable_devices') attr to this m2m

The following code is for the second method

```
class PlatformDevice(models.Model):
    name = 'Property Specifics'
    property_field = models.ForeignKey('Property', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    event_group = models.ForeignKey('EventGroups', blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    applicable_devices = models.ForeignKey('Device', blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    platform = models.ForeignKey('Platform', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Property(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    applicable_platform = models.ManyToManyField('Platform', through=PlatformDevice,
                                                 through_fields = ('event_group', 'applicable_devices')
                                                )
```

I hope it helps you